# React Custom Hooks and useEffect infinite re-renders

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

```js
export const useMyCustomHook = () => {
    const uiLoad = useUiLoad(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        // ...
    }, [...]);
}
```

`uiLoad` is a custom hook (as is, obviously, `useMyCustomHook`). This works fine **if** I don't add `uiLoad` to the `useEffect` dependency array. If I do include it, it infinitely re-renders.
Here's my code for the `uiLoad` hook:

```js
const baseDispatch = {
    type: SET_LOADING
}

export const useUiLoad = (initial: boolean = false) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch<Dispatch<UIAction>>();
    const loaded = useRef(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (initial && !loaded.current) {
            console.log('Called');
            dispatch({
                type: SET_LOADING,
                loadbarShowing: true
            });
            loaded.current= true;
        }
    }, [dispatch, initial])
    return (loading: boolean) => {
        const data: UIAction = {
            ...baseDispatch,
            loadbarShowing: loading
        }
        dispatch(data);
    }
}
```

As far as I know, hooks don't change on re-render. So the questions are:

1. Why is uiLoad changing on every rerender? Using the [`useWhatChanged`](https://github.com/simbathesailor/use-what-changed) debugger tool I can find that it is, indeed, changing everytime the component re-renders. Don't hooks stay the same every render? Or does that not apply to custom hooks?
2. Is the only solution here supressing the warning using `// eslint-disable-next-line`?

Comment: `useUiLoad` returns a *new* function each time it's called, try memoizing the returned function in a `useCallback` hook.

Comment: @DrewReese That should have been obvious to me, and it worked. Do post this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hooks are called each time the component is rendered. The `useUiLoad` returns a *new* function each time it's called. You can return a memoized function so it's a stable reference.

```
export const useUiLoad = (initial: boolean = false) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch<Dispatch<UIAction>>();
  const loaded = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (initial && !loaded.current) {
      console.log('Called');
      dispatch({
        type: SET_LOADING,
        loadbarShowing: true
      });
      loaded.current= true;
    }
  }, [dispatch, initial]);

  return useCallback((loading: boolean) => {
    const data: UIAction = {
      ...baseDispatch,
      loadbarShowing: loading
    }
    dispatch(data);
  }, [dispatch]); // <-- add any other dependencies if necessary
}
```